# awk to remove fields and spaces or data in it

Tags: awk

In the below `tab-delimited` `file` I am trying to remove `$1` and `$9` and the empty space or data in it.  My two attempts seem to remove `$1` and the data in it only.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  Inheritence ID
1   chr1    40562993    40562993    T   C   UTR5    PPT1    NM_000310.3:c.-83A>G        1
```

**awk**

```
awk '{sub(/^[^\t]*\t/, "")
gsub(/ /, "")
}1
' file    

awk -F'\t' '{$1=x;sub(/^\t/,y)}1' OFS='\t' file

awk -F'\t' '{$1 && $9=x;sub(/^\t/,y)}1' OFS='\t' file
```

**desired output**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  ID
chr1    40562993    40562993    T   C   UTR5    PPT1    NM_000310.3:c.-83A>G    1
```

Comment: first line has `11` fields, second line has `10` fields .... is `"\t"` the separator? .... please to fix input example

Comment: I edited the `file` and yes, sorry for that, it is `tab-delimited' as well as the `output`. There are `11` fiels in `file` and the `9` in the `output` as two fields and there data/blanks are removed.  Thank you :).

Comment: Please, show us the code lines which try to remove the `$9`.

Comment: I updated the `awk` to try and remove `$9`.  Thank you :).

Comment: Doesn't `cut -f2-8,10-` work?

Comment: Yes it does, I am not familiar with `cut` but if you make  it an answer I will accept it.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{sub(/[^ ]+ /,"",$1);sub(/[^ ]+ /,"",$NF)}1' file1 | 
  column -t

Chr   Start     End       Ref  Alt  Func.IDP.refGene  Gene.IDP.refGene  GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  ID
chr1  40562993  40562993  T    C    UTR5              PPT1              NM_000310.3:c.-83A>G    1
```